# Starting jenkins connection as jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, hudson

I think this is very simple question but can't find solution anywhere. I have to run my jenkins plist file ( or just .jar file ) as jenkins, not as an admin. This is how my file looks right now:

```
<key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sudo</string>
        <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
        <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/slave.jar</string>
        <string>-jnlpUrl</string>
        <string>http://[adres]/slave-agent.jnlp
</string>
        <string>-secret</string>
        <string>841557ed784ead7secret[334b3ac76fe1618e375
</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/error.log</string>
```

I was trying to add command to switch to jenkins with:

> sudo su jenkins

so I tried adding something like this:

```
<key>Jenkins user</key>
        <string>what.to.put.here</string>
        <key>OtherArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>sudo</string>
            <string>su</string>
            <string>jenkins</string>
        </array>
```

before those lines above, but as I see I'm still not logged as jenkins. When I do this from command line with those commands I wrote - than it works, but I want it to run when system starts.

**EDIT:**

after **gaige** answer I added:

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>jenkins</string>
```

but I still don't have permissions to directory to which jenkins user has.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a system launchctl plist, then you can just add the `UserName` key:

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>jenkins</string>
```

at the same level as your other keys in the plist.  And then remove all the `sudo` related stuff.

Note that this must be a system launchd (located in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemon` or `/Library/LaunchDaemon`), otherwise you won't have permissions to use the user in question.

Comment: well I'm quite new to mac - how to differ system launchdaemon from others? or did You mean exactly system.plist or something similar?

Comment: If it's in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` then it is a system launchdaemon.  If it's located in you home directory's `Library/LaunchDameons` or `Library/LaunchAgents` folder, then it's a personal plist.

Comment: well it is located in /Library/LaunchDaemons. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That's also run as root, so it would be fine.

Comment: eh, build in jenkins still throws that I don't have permission to given directory. jenkins user on this mac has those permission ( although in user's managment this account is called "jenkins_test" but owner of this directory is "jenkins" ). I'm a little bit lost..

Comment: If you don't have permission to the directory, you're going to either need to change the target directory to somewhere else or use `sudo` to change the ownership of the directory to the `jenkins` user.  It sounds as if you already ran Jenkins using another user, which is going to create the directory structure with the ownership of that user.

Comment: no, owner of the directory is jenkins, everything is in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home directory and admin does not have permission to fetch from git there. When in terminal I switch user to jenkins and than connect to my build server - everything works fine, but when I'm connecting as an admin - well, I don't have permissions..

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you any further.  The permission problem should be pretty simple to resolve: make sure the jenkins user can read/write/execute to the home directory and everything beneath that. Then make sure that you are exciting the daemon as that jenkins user as well.  Finally, make sure that you set up the correct user permissions for executing any commands, such as for your source control system.  I would strongly suggest that when testing this manually that you log in (via SSH or the GUI) as the jenkins user so that you don't run the risk of having a different effective user.

Comment: well I've been looking for work-around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881326/bash-script-running-from-launchdaemon-on-mac-not-connecting-to-jenkins