# Bash script running from launchDaemon on MAC - not connecting to jenkins

Tags: ios, macos, bash, jenkins

I've got very simple plist file which is supposed to run my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/my_scripts/run_jenkins.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/error.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and when I run it nothing happens - I mean when I run `sh run_jenkins.sh` it connects to my jenkins server. But when I run it from `sudo launchctl org.jenkins-ci.plist` then it doesn't connect. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do those log files contain anything useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "load" or start command in the launchctl:

```
sudo launchctl load -w org.jenkins-ci.plist

sudo launchctl start org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

You should probably also make your script executable, using

```
chmod +x "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/my_scripts/run_jenkins.sh"
```

And remove the "sh" line in your plist file.

And make sure your script starts with the correct shebang line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

And set the permissions on your plist file:

```
chmod 644 org.jenkins-ci.plist
```